# Using CsvReader From LumenWorks with ";" delimiter

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, csv

I have two little issues with the `CsvReader` from LumenWorks.

First one my `*.csv` files has a `;` delimiter. Not a big deal I just have to change the delimiter property in the reader but it is actually a little more tricky than that because headers ends with a `;` too but not the rows.

For example :

```
Column1;Column2;Column3;
1;Michael;Page
2;Michael;Jackson
...
```

Is there a way to indicate it to the reader?

And second issue how can I select dynamically the columns to import?

My code is written as follow:

```
Public Sub ImportCSV2Data(ByVal filename As String, ByRef gridToShow As GridControl, ByVal column2Import() As Integer)
    Dim csvCopy As CachedCsvReader = New CachedCsvReader(New StreamReader(filename), True, ";"c)
    Dim processedCopy = csvCopy.Select(Function(showColumn) New With{.SAPNo = column(0),.CCode = column(2)})

    gridToShow.DataSource = processedCopy
End Sub
```

But how can I make the selected column depends on values in column2Import?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relying on a `CSVReader` is not a bad thing but if you have special requirements, perhaps it would be easier to rely on the conventional `StreamReader` rather than spending time on carrying out the required modifications. Sample code:

```
 Dim sr As System.IO.StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader("target CSV file path")
 Dim line As String

 'Adapt this code to retrieve the column names from the file itself or from other source
 Dim getColumnNames As Boolean = True
 Dim columnNames() As String = Nothing

 Do
     line = sr.ReadLine()
     If (line IsNot Nothing) Then
         if(line.Contains(";")) then
             If (columnNames Is Nothing And getColumnNames) Then
                 columnNames = line.Split(";")
             Else
                 Dim curRowVals() As String = line.Split(";")
                 'All the row values
             End If
         End If
     End If
 Loop Until line Is Nothing
```

Comment: I have a NullReferenceException on `If (line IsNot Nothing And line.Contains(";")) Then`

Comment: @rave the whole point of my answer is proposing a simple line-by-line reading. You can store all the rows in a 2D array, create as many arrays as columns or even perform the actions you want per row (right after reading). The reading process is slower than in your approach but this proceeding allows you to have full control on each record.

Comment: If we replace the `And` by `AndAlso` we don't have the error anymore. And your code is really a nice idea but the fact is that i have 20k lines in my csv that's why I tried to use csvreader to have a fast reading process.
Mayby can I try to open the csv file delete the last `;` from the headers line, save it and read it by csvreader?

Comment: @Rave I am not so sure that the CSVreader is so much faster than the conventional streamreader. Just the fact of opening and editing the file implies losing too much time. Also CSVreader is not as flexible as the code proposed above. Why not testing this code with your 20k file and see how long it takes? PS: thanks for the AndAlso comment; lately, I am usually programming in C# and, some times, forget about these VB details.

Comment: @Rave Your AndAlso comment is nice (mainly for persons more used to C#) but the correction I introduced is also fine and thus don't need to be changed. Even the loop might have a while on top and thus the isnot nothing condition (or AndAlso) can be ignored. There are many options which are OK; the important thing here is the applicability of this code to your specific situation (btw, this specific streamreader code comes directly from MSDN).

Comment: Because I can't make it work ;) (I'm a beginner)
I tried to add each curRowVals() in an arrayList and then link this arraylist to the datasource but I have the same issue which I mentioned in the answer from Tim Schmelter

Comment: @Rave I understand your problem now!!! You are not understanding the dimensions you are dealing with properly. Try a simple approach to make it work (which I hope you will analyse further and come up with the best configuration to your situation). I will put it via comment because does not really affect my answer (= rely on conventional streamreader and deal with all the information from it). Do this...

Comment: @Rave Dim datatable As DataTable = New DataTable()
datatable.Columns.Add(0)
datatable.Columns.Add(1)
datatable.Columns.Add(2)          After getting the values for each row (which actually are arrays of values), write this:                     Dim curRowVals() As String = line.Split(";")
                    datatable.Rows.Add(curRowVals(0), curRowVals(1), curRowVals(2))   In this way you will be writing the corresponding rows/columns to the datatable. Outside the loop, assign the datatable to the datagridview, by doing: DataGridView1.DataSource = datatable

Comment: @Rave In this way you are storing all the data properly (by respecting the dimensions) and thus you might assign it to the datagridview without any problem. Bear in mind that this code assumes. at least, three columns. You can change this datatable (which is basically a 2D array) as much as you want and thus decide which columns/rows will be displayed in the datagridview. I hope that you will be able to make it work this time.

Comment: It worked perfectly and I can't see the difference in time of process. When I see your code now it seems logic. I have still some modifications to do but I now know how to get there.

Comment: @Rave I am happy to read that. In any case, bear in mind that there is a processing-time difference almost for sure; although it is not too relevant (on the range of milliseconds) and that's why you don't feel it (at least for small datasets).

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "second issue" how to select a subset of columns:

```
Dim result As IEnumerable(Of String()) = csvCopy.
    Select(Function(fields) fields.Where(Function(f, i) column2Import.Contains(i))
                                  .ToArray())
```

Comment: It doesn't work instead of my csv datas I have columns with Length, Long Length, Rank, Sync Root, Is Read Only,... It looks like the same issue then when I call CsvReader instead of CachedCsvReader.

Comment: Column2Import contains the index of the columns that has to be selected (sorry if i wasn't clear enough).

Comment: @Rave: The linq query selects only column-indexes which are in `column2Import`. The `fields` objects for every line contains all columns as `String[]`, the [overload of `Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) which provides the index is used to select only the desired columns. The `ToArray` creates a new array from those.

Answer (score 0):

After a good night of sleep I got this idea :

```
Dim csvCopy As CachedCsvReader = New CachedCsvReader(New StreamReader(filename), True, ";"c)
csvCopy.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty

Dim headers() As String = csvCopy.GetFieldHeaders
For Each column As Integer In column2Import
    datatable.Columns.Add(headers(column))
Next
While csvCopy.ReadNextRecord()
    Dim csvRow As DataRow = datatable.NewRow
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each column As Integer In column2Import
        csvRow(i) = csvCopy(column)
        i += 1
    Next
    datatable.Rows.Add(csvRow)
End While
```

The `csvCopy.MissingFieldAction = MissingFieldAction.ReplaceByEmpty` resolves my second issue and the rest my first one

Answer (score 0):

I think Lumen has this capability now.
The below worked for me. I was using pipes separator in the below example.

```
var reader = new CsvReader(File.OpenText(csvPath), true,'|'));
```